# Simpletest's browser tries to access the non-testing database

Tags: 8, testing

I want to test my Drupal 8 module via simpletest. If I use the $this->drupalGet(); method, the test's browser tries to access the real database. Not the database which has been created for the tests.

I can see this by the test report in the browser:
[image]

I am using the following command to run the tests.

> php core/scripts/run-tests.sh --url http://pbt-d8 --browser
>   --verbose --color --concurrency 4 --class 'Drupal\permissions_by_term\Tests\RestrictedNodeTest'

This is the code of my test:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\permissions_by_term\Tests;

use Drupal\permissions_by_term\AccessCheckService;
use Drupal\permissions_by_term\AccessStorageService;
use Drupal\simpletest\WebTestBase;
use Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Vocabulary;
use Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term;
use Drupal\user\Entity\User;
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;
use Drupal\Core\Language\LanguageInterface;
use Drupal\field\Entity\FieldStorageConfig;
use Drupal\field\Entity\FieldConfig;

/**
 * Tests access restriction to nodes.
 *
 * Example command to run this test:
 * php core/scripts/run-tests.sh --url http://pbt-d8 --browser --verbose
 * --color --concurrency 4 --class
 * 'Drupal\permissions_by_term\Tests\RestrictedNodeTest'
 *
 * Make sure that the folder at /sites/simpletest is writable.
 *
 * @group permissions_by_term
 */
class RestrictedNodeTest extends WebTestBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static $modules = array('node', 'taxonomy', 'text', 'permissions_by_term');

  /**
   * List of taxonomy term names by language.
   *
   * @var array
   */
  public $term_names = [];

  /**
   * The vocabulary used for creating terms.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\taxonomy\VocabularyInterface
   */
  protected $vocabulary;

  protected $test_node_id;

  /**
   * Sets up the test.
   */
  protected function setUp() {
    parent::setUp();

    // Create a vocabulary.
    $this->vocabulary = Vocabulary::create([
      'name' => $this->randomMachineName(),
      'description' => $this->randomMachineName(),
      'vid' => $this->randomMachineName(),
      'langcode' => LanguageInterface::LANGCODE_NOT_SPECIFIED,
      'help' => '',
    ]);
    $this->vocabulary->save();

    // Setup an authenticated user for our tests.
    $this->authenticated = User::create(array(
      'name' => $this->randomMachineName(),
      'mail' => 'non_admin@example.com',
      'roles' => array(),
      'pass' => user_password(),
      'status' => 1,
    ));
    // @TODO: user is being saved, but no user id has been returned.
    $user_created = $this->authenticated->save();

    // Add a term to the vocabulary.
    $term = Term::create([
      'name' => $this->randomMachineName(),
      'description' => $this->randomMachineName(),
      'vid' => $this->vocabulary->id(),
      'langcode' => LanguageInterface::LANGCODE_NOT_SPECIFIED,
    ]);
    $term->save();

    $oDbConnection = \Drupal::database();
    $access_storage_service = new AccessStorageService($oDbConnection, NULL, $term->id());
    // @TODO: remove 3 and add real user id.
    $access_storage_service->addTermPermissionsByUserIds([4]);

    FieldStorageConfig::create([
      'entity_type' => 'node',
      'field_name' => 'field_tags',
      'type' => 'entity_reference',
      'settings' => [
        'target_type' => 'taxonomy_term',
      ],
    ])->save();

    $this->drupalCreateContentType(['type' => 'article']);
    FieldConfig::create([
      'field_name' => 'field_tags',
      'entity_type' => 'node',
      'bundle' => 'article',
    ])->save();

    $node = Node::create([
      'type' => 'article',
      'title' => 'test node',
      'field_tags' => [$term->id()],
    ]);

    $node_save_ret = $node->save();

    $this->assertTrue($node_save_ret, 'Node could be saved.');

    $this->test_node_id = $node->id();

    $account = $this->drupalCreateUser();
    $this->drupalLogin($account);

    $access_check_service = new AccessCheckService();
    $ret = $access_check_service->canUserAccessByNodeId(1);

    // Visit a Drupal page that requires login.
    $drupal_get_ret = $this->drupalGet('node/1');

    $this->assertText('Access denied');

  }

  public function testAccess() {


    //$this->assertResponse(200, 'Page was accessible');
  }

}
```

How can I force the test's browser to use the testing database?

Comment: How do you know it's using another database?

Comment: You created the node and then called drupalGet. .. might want to update the question for clarity.

Comment: In tests results, always fix problems on the top first. Most likely, those errors are related to simplenews failing to properly set up the environment, you need to fix that first. Check file permissions and ownership. You must run tests with the same user as apache is running. sudo -u www-data or whatever it is in your case. On my local systems, I always configure apache to use my personal user.

Comment: Even I run the command with sudo, I get the mkdir() errors.The sites/default/files folder has 777 permissions.